# How do I specify time in "For Every 1.00 am of Friday" in milliseconds Java for a cron job?

Tags: java, time, cron, scheduled-tasks, jobs

Hi I am trying to writing a class to schedule a job at a specific time. Here is the code,

```
public void test(){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
        date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

        //schedule to run on 1 am every friday. 
        timer.schedule(new JobRunner(), date.getTime(),1*0*0*0);
    }
```

Please help on the last line, I am not sure how to specify the time in there.

Thanks

Comment: Don't reinvent wheel. Take a look and/or use the Quartz scheduler cronTrigger http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps.

```
    static final long period = 7*24*60*60*1000;//one week

public void test(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    //in case you run the batch before date
    if (date.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
    }        

    long delay =  date.getTimeInMillis() - new Date().getTime();              
    //schedule to run on 1 am every friday. 
    timer.schedule(new JobRunner(), delay, period);              
}
```

Regards!